# How to combine data from two google sheet and exclude the empty row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have 2 google sheets with data as shown in the screenshot above. For the first google sheet, the empty row are row 3 & row 7. For the second google sheet, the empty row are row 2, row 7 and row 10. I want to combine these two google sheets in a master google sheet. This is what I used to combine the data and the result that I get:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1BT3KLMGoE3FMaiW8G1ig6GRTyaJnYcskSaIeki7m-gs","Sheet1!A1:J100"),IMPORTRANGE("1gW5rEiinQe-PaqvFH890ZXXx7YnSVtmUghhpTl7lGng","Sheet1!A1:J100")},"where Col2 is not null")
```

[image]

As you can see, the data from second google sheet start from `Column K` and row 3 data is missing. I want to start the data from second google sheet in row 9 instead of `Column K`. May I know what I did wrong in the `QUERY` and `IMPORTRANGE` and how to avoid missing the data from second google sheet (row 3 data)?

Hope to get some helps and advices, thank you.

Comment: Try replacing comma `,` before the 2nd `IMPORTRANGE` with semi-colon `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

- As per kishkin's comment,

> Try replacing comma , before the 2nd IMPORTRANGE with semi-colon

#### Formula:

`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1BT3KLMGoE3FMaiW8G1ig6GRTyaJnYcskSaIeki7m-gs","Sheet1!A1:J100");IMPORTRANGE("1gW5rEiinQe-PaqvFH890ZXXx7YnSVtmUghhpTl7lGng","Sheet1!A1:J100")},"where Col2 is not null")`

Delimiter used is <kbd>,</kbd> instead of <kbd>;</kbd>. I assume you are located most likely in Europe and that is the reason of the issue. See reason below.

#### Reason:

> Locations using decimal points:
>
> For locations using periods (or points or dots or whatever you call them) to denote decimal separators (most non-European countries including US, UK, Australia), the syntax will follow this structure:
>
> - Decimals will be denoted by a decimal point (a period)
> - Arguments in formulas separated by a comma
> - Horizontal data in curly-brace arrays separated by a comma
>
> Locations using decimal commas:
>
> For locations using commas to denote decimal separators (most European countries), the syntax will follow this structure:
>
> - Decimals will be denoted by a comma
> - Arguments in formulas separated by a semi-colon
> - Horizontal data in curly-brace arrays separated by a back-slash

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- [Sheets Location](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/)